# Just want to print cell data from excel file Using PHPExcel?

Tags: php, html, phpexcel

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
set_time_limit(0);

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

?>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<title>PHPExcel Reader Example #09</title>

</head>
<body>


<?php

/** Include path **/
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '../../../Classes/');

/** PHPExcel_IOFactory */
include 'C:\webserver\www\Classes\PHPExcel\IOFactory.php';


$inputFileType = 'Excel5';
//  $inputFileType = 'Excel2007';
//  $inputFileType = 'Excel2003XML';
//  $inputFileType = 'OOCalc';
//  $inputFileType = 'Gnumeric';
$inputFileName = './sampleData/Book1.xls';
$sheetname = 'Data Sheet #3';


class MyReadFilter implements PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter
{
    public function readCell($column, $row, $worksheetName = '') {

        if ($row >= 1 && $row <= 1) {
            if (in_array($column,range('A','A'))) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}

$filterSubset = new MyReadFilter();

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly($sheetname);
$objReader->setReadFilter($filterSubset);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
$sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
var_dump($sheetData);


?>
<body>
</html>
```

When i run aboce code it gives me this output

```
array(1) { [1]=> array(1) { ["A"]=> string(6) "ABCDEF" } }
```

In above output ABCDEF is first cell data. so i want only ABCDEF not other things as shown above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because you asked PHPExcel to give you the *whole worksheet* as an array.

If you just want the value of cell A1 use:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A1')->getValue();
```

instead of

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
```

More about this in [the documentation](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/releases/view/96183), in this case the file "PHPExcel developer documentation.pdf".

You can then also remove the read filter altogether. The cells are read in a lazy manner, so you don't save anything with the read filter if you only access cell A1 directly anyway.

Comment: string(6) "ABCDEF"
this output i got by using above line of code you said.

Comment: Go find out about the difference between [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/var_dump) and [`echo`](http://php.net/echo).

Answer (score 0):

include '`C:\webserver\www\Classes\PHPExcel\IOFactory.php`';

this include file which is include by me file in this file.